# Form request validation not firing

Tags: php, html, forms

On successful form submission, I should be seeing 'in here' within the browser but I get re-directed to a page not found view:

Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

My form control:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'prize_draw_store', 'class' => 'wffm-form-module text-left']) !!}

    {!! Form::label('fullname', 'Name:', array('class' => 'control-label')) !!}
    {!! Form::text('fullname', null, array('required', 'class'=>'form-control text-box single-line', 'placeholder'=>'')) !!}

    {!! Form::label('email_address', 'Email Address:', array('class' => 'control-label')) !!}
    {!! Form::text('email_address', null, array('required', 'class'=>'form-control text-box single-line', 'placeholder'=>'')) !!}

    <div class="form-submit-border">
        {{ Form::submit('Submit', array('class' => 'btn btn-default')) }}
    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

My routes are well-defined:

*/routes/web.php*

```
use App\Http\Controllers\PrizeDrawController;
use App\Http\Requests\PrizeDrawFormRequest;

Route::get('/', 
 ['as' => 'prize_draw', 'uses' => 'PrizeDrawController@create']);

Route::post('/', 
 ['as' => 'prize_draw_store', 'uses' => 'PrizeDrawController@store']);
```

*PrizeDrawController.php*

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\PrizeDrawFormRequest;


class PrizeDrawController extends Controller
{
  public function create() {
    return view('front.pages.home');
  }
  public function store(PrizeDrawFormRequest $request) {
    var_dump('in here');
    return redirect('thankyou')->with('status', 'Form submitted!');
  }
 }
```

*PrizeDrawFormRequest.php*

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class PrizeDrawFormRequest extends FormRequest
{
 public function authorize()
 {
    return true;
 }

 public function rules()
 {
    return [
        'email_address' => 'required|email',
        'fullname' => 'required'
    ];
 }
}
```

I'm expecting the code to flow like thus:

```
1. http://aacomp.local/prize_draw_store -- POST form submission
2. App\Http\Controllers\PrizeDrawController@store
3. PrizeDrawController::store(PrizeDrawFormRequest $request)
4. Redirect a user to thankyou page
```

We don't seem to reach step 3 though? I must be missing something basic -
 are you able to help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what it shows after you submit?

Comment: The dreaded: Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found page.

Comment: 'url' => 'prize_draw_store' -  try to use real url here. What happens then?

Comment: Same result - page not found

Comment: return redirect('thankyou') - what is 'thankyou' - maybe a route name which is not found?

Comment: I'm not concerned with route name not found since the script should be hitting: `var_dump('in here');` before this step. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162285/discussion-between-darius-v-and-cookie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies with:

```
Route::post('/', 
 ['as' => 'prize_draw_store', 'uses' => 'PrizeDrawController@store']);
```

Changing this route to

```
Route::post('/foobar', 
 ['as' => 'prize_draw_store', 'uses' => 'PrizeDrawController@store']);
```

and updating the form action:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'foobar', ...
```

say - will get the desired results. Thanks to Darius. V for this.